# EditText Drawable Background For Each State

Tags: android

I want to customize my background. So I design shape in selector for each state. but the first item execute.

This is my code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#8faefd" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

[State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom
>   and the first item that matches the current state is used—the
>   selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item
>   that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

So you have to swap this two items. Should be like that

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#8faefd" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```